# Declare a method with two generic parameters

Tags: c#

Trying to do the following:

```
public static class Qbo<T> where T : class
{
    public static List<Items> Convert(List<T> list1, List<T> list2)
    {
         // Merging lists of different types into one list
    }
}
```

Calling like this:

```
var items = Qbo<Bill>.Convert(bills, billPayments);
var moreItems = Qbo<Invoice>.Convert(invoices, payments);
```

But I get an error because the method tries to accept the first list type as the second list type. Any ideas?

Comment: Then declare two generic types: `Convert<T, U>(...)`

Comment: What *is* the error you get? And what are `bills` and `payments` datatypes?

Comment: You are declaring that the two list types are the same - `T`.

Comment: Right now this method won't even compile unless this is enclosed in a generic class with a type T parameter.

Comment: So when you get the method signature right, I'm curious what are you going to do inside it, especially as you seem to know the return type.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys, probably would help if I added some more context.

Comment: My post below answers the bulk of your question, but if you explain how you think you can merge those lists together when they are different types, there may be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your edit it's a little clearer what you need. You already have `T` from the class definition, but you now need another generic type for the method. So make the method call generic too:

```
public static class Qbo<T> where T : class
{
    public static List<Items> Convert<U>(List<T> list1, List<U> list2)
    //                               ^^^                    ^^^
    {
         // Merging lists of different types into one list
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When you *expect* different datatypes for the type-parameters you should also *declare* them differently:

```
public static List<Items> Convert<T, U>(List<T> list1, List<U> list2)
```

You should also note that you have to add the type-parameters to the methods declaration itself asshown above unless they are not already declared via the class you´re in.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that your parameters are of different types, so you would use multiple generics. I believe that it should look something like this.

```
public static List<Items> Convert<T, U> (List<T> list1, List<U> list2)
{
}
```

Here is the documentation on generics which should cover methods with multiple generics. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: This is almost identical to the answer posted, and even my comment above...

Comment: Furthermore the links doesn´t help much as it is in VB and more important it doesn´t handle **methods** with generic type-parameters, instead it handles **classess** with type-parameters.